# Move File to External Storage and Create Alias in Place on Mac

Tags: macos, backup, monterey, alias

I am looking for setting up a backup system such that in which I can conveniently move the original file to the backup location, but it creates an alias (pointing towards the file now in the backup location) in the place from where the file was moved.

So essentially the file is moved to the backup location and hence is not taking up space anymore on the internal storage, but the folder structure remains intact and hence I can easily navigate to that file, now on external storage.

I hope I was able to put clearly what I am looking for. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. This is what iCloud does if you set it to optimise space on your Mac, but it must be stressed **iCloud is not a backup system**. Otherwise this doesn't seem a sensible course of action. You don't mention what sort of files you hope to utilise in this plan. Why not just move the items and forget about your aliases, and just accept the items are in a different location? Otherwise, for proper versioned backup, just use Time Machine. It sounds like you could do with clarifying why you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, Andy, yes I agree that's precisely what iCloud does, the issue with using the cloud is that every time I have to use that file I'll have to download that file from the cloud hence making it inefficient. So I was wondering if I could set it up in a way that there is the alias of that file and when I click it opens up from the external storage. Thanks

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use iCloud, but just drawing a comparison between what iCloud does and what you think you want to do. Also you misunderstand what iCloud is doing in that circumstance. It only 'links' to the file when it needs to if optimise space is set **and** the file has been offloaded due to space issues. It is not inefficient at all. You still haven't explained why you want to do this, or even at a more fundamental level, what problem you think you are solving by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a very good idea, though it is possible to some extent.

You do realise that will not make it a 'backup'. It will still be the only location for that file.

Move the file to its new location.
Right click it & 'Make Alias'
Copy or move the alias back to the original location.

This will only work for *some* structures, such as contents of your documents folder. It will not work for System protected locations, such as your actual Documents folder.
It is likely not to work in file-picker boxes.

Some structures can be moved & the pointer simply set in prefs to the new location. Such as your iTunes/Music Library or Photos library work perfectly well this way, no aliasing required.

Comment: Hi! yes I think the word backup is not accurate here, it's more like archiving a file to the external storage so it does not take up space on the internal storage and I can still access it by clicking it from the same place. Secondly, the way you mentioned is the manual way of doing it, I was wondering if an automatic workaround could be setup, but thanks anyways!

Comment: It's not even really an archive. It's just "in another place" no safer than any other single location. There's no automatic method. The only alternative is a slightly more complicated symlink you'd have to make in terminal, but the end result is very similar to making an alias in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can move the original main file itself to the external disk,
2. Find the file on the external disk, then make an alias to it in the Finder on that external disk,
3. Then drag the alias off the external disk to the main computer's Finder desktop screen.